# How exactly does this work sum()?

Tags: java, python, sum

This is in Python. I'm trying to figure out exactly how this works so I can translate it to Java.

```
numInversions = sum(
    state.index(START[j]) > state.index(START[i])
    for i in range(16) for j in range(i)  # each pair (i,j)
)
```

Comment: i pretty much understand it, except how the > operator works, the result from it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
numInversions = 0
for i in range(16):
    for j in range(i):
        if state.index(START[j]) > state.index(START[i]):
            numInversions += 1
```

The `>` returns a `bool`, which is equivalent to `0` or `1`.

Comment: thanks man i been up for so long, looking around like crazy, thanks

Comment: thats actually what i was thinking, im just checking myself before i go coding, thanks again

Answer (score 2):

The Code is similar to the verbose format

```
numInversions = =
for i in range(16):
    for j in range(i):
        if state.index(START[j]) > state.index(START[i]):
            numInversions += 1
```

Except that the entire expression is wrapped as a generator expression and passed to the built-in sum

The nested loop construct is read from left to right so it unfoldes to

```
for i in range(16):
    for j in range(i):
```

The Condition which evaluates to a boolean True or False is summed up. So you end up counting all instances which the condition evaluates to True

Answer (score 2):

The inner loop generates boolean values (`True` and `False`) based on the two nested loops. IN Python, booleans are a subclass of `int` and when summed act as `1` and `0` for `True` and `False`, respectively.

So, you could rewrite this as:

```
numInversions = 0
for i in range(16):
    for j in range(i):
        if state.index(START[j]) > state.index(START[i]):
            numInversions += 1
```

Answer (score 2):

In (pseudo-)Java:

```
int numInversions = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 16; ++i) {
  for (int j = 0; j < i; ++j) {
    if (state.index(START[j]) > state.index(START[i])) {
      ++numInversions;
    }
  }
}
```